# Does lithium aluminium hydride react with conjugated dienes?

Tags: organic-chemistry, organic-reduction

I have searched many websites, but was unable to find if $\ce{LiAlH4}$ is able to reduce conjugated dienes, such as styrene to ethylbenzene or 1,3-butadiene to 1-butene.

Comment: It doesn't, if it could you should have been able to find an example of that.

Comment: I agree, it does not reduce alkenes or poly-alkenes